# jquery sorting on button click

Tags: jquery, sorting

I using jquery sorting (http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/). Is it possible to sort (move list) only when I click on specitic div or image?

For example only when I click on black arrows (upper example).

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#option-handle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a selector in the [handle](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#option-handle) option:

```
$("#sortable").sortable({
    handle: ".ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"
});
```

You can test it in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2rT82/).